# Return value of Qdialog execution

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

I am calling a QDialog on a click event of a QPushButton. I want to execute that dialog 
as a Qt::Sheet or Qt::Drawer. For this i am using exec()

```
int Qdialog::exec();
```

method but it executes it as 
a popup dialog instead of Qt::Sheet or Qt::Drawer. I have also tried show method,

```
void Qdialog::show();
```

it works fine but here my problem is, its return type is void and my further
working depends on its return type like exec() method. 
thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`show()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#show) will not block, that is why it can't return anything. `QDialog` has a [`finished`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qdialog.html#finished) signal which has the result as an argument. You can use that to get the result after calling `show()`.